# Can a WiFi station be hand luggage?

Tags: hand-luggage

I bought a new WiFi station (TP-Link) but I have only hand luggage. 
In AirBaltic, it costs 36 euros to have the thing in the main luggage, which is too expensive.

Can you have a WiFi station in a hand luggage?

Comment: Will it fit in your hand baggage allowance?

Comment: Yes. It will fit easily.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the answer is the same than for your other question. As WiFi stations are not listed in the [list of forbidden items](http://ec.europa.eu/transport/modes/air/security/doc/info_travellers_hand_luggage.pdf) you should be able of carrying one in your hand luggage. The only restriction that you should find is that it might be turned off for the entire flight.